# MIME Type error: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of 'application/octet-stream'.'"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, github, github-pages, vite

My site works and renders in the browser perfectly locally, but when accessing it through the custom domain I have associated with GitHub Pages, I get the error:

"Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of 'application/octet-stream'.'"

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I worked for days trying to solve this issue.

- custom domain: andreamalone.com

- hosted through GitHub Pages

- React Vite.js Typescript app